# How to Get Min-width Media-Query to Work for Mobile-First Design

Tags: css, media-queries

I am designing my web app to be **mobile-first** in design by using only the `min-width` `media-query`. However it is not working as how it should work! Instead of content being smaller at and below a screen-size of 500px, it is larger instead. And instead of content being larger at above a minimum screen-size of 500px, it is smaller. I want all content to be smaller at and below a minimum screen-size of 500px, and larger at screen sizes larger than 500px. I also want to have the "Generate Quote" and "Tweet" button shifted up or down to accommodate the changes induced by the min-width media-query

You can view my CodePen here: https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/KZqNdr/

Here is my CSS code:

```
.container{
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("https://s25.postimg.org/9pnce8yr3/galaxy-s8_overview_kv_type1b.jpg");
    /**https://s25.postimg.org/exhm9rejz/galaxy-s8_overview_kv_type1.jpg"**/
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    /**border: 3px solid grey;**/   
}



h1{
    color: white;
}



.Motorcycle{
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    /**border: 1px solid grey;**/
    text-align: center;

}

/**
.cropper{
    border-radius: 80px;
    opacity: 0.85;
}
**/

.btn.btn-default{
  color: #0040ff;
  font-size: .80em;
  font-family: Orbitron, sans-serif;
  line-height: 4em;  


}

.gstuff{
  background-image: url("https://s25.postimg.org/onteix7u7/G_Motorcycle_Helmet_3.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 350px;
    height: 477px;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0.85;

}

#push-one{
  transform: translateY(200px);
  background-color: #c6c6c4;
  border-bottom:2px inset #FFF;
  border-right:2px inset #FFF;
  border-radius:15px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
}

#push-two{
  transform: translateY(530px);
  background-color: #c6c6c4;
  border-bottom:2px inset #FFF;
  border-right:2px inset #FFF;
  border-radius:7px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: blue;
}



@media(min-width: 500px){
  .gstuff{ 
  width: 250px;
  height: 341px;
  }
}
```

I achieved an adequate mobile-first `min-width`with this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/NwNOgq): , but I'm having a hard time achieving it with [this one](https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/KZqNdr/)

Comment: I adjusted your codepen and forked it to this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJZMNb I just set your container to be an id instead of class, added a 4% margin  (top and bottom) to the gstuff and changed the min-width to max-width

Comment: @RachelGallen thankyou! This is exactly what I wanted! Now I just need to find a way to fix the buttons and make them remain in the same positions simultaneously.

Comment: Glad to help. Can you clarify how you want the buttons to line up?

Comment: Hi, @RachelGallen,  I want the buttons to line up like this: [https://s25.postimg.org/awoxgro27/G_Motorcycle_Helmet_4.jpg] The larger button will be at the top, and the smaller will be at the bottom. I want to make it then even when the motorcycle helmet shrinks per screen size that the button will shift to make up for that same location.....later I'm going to a text box to go in the middle (the glass) where that blue outline is. Thanks! Just trying to design with an industrial design aesthetic lol :)

Comment: you can adjust the translateY to make this happen I think. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJZMNb) again  (adjust values if necessary)

Comment: That's what I was thinking too.....gonna add some values to it to change it a little bit, here and there...you are awesome!

Comment: Hi @RachelGallen, I'm just realizing that you used `max-width`max-width is easy, my issue is I want to design the web page to be "mobile-first" using `min-width` instead. It's a more difficult process but well worth it! Currently this is what you have `@media(max-width: 500px){
  .gstuff{ 
  width: 250px;
  height: 341px;
  }
}`

Comment: "mobile-first" design is a fancy name for responsive design, i.e. the use of media queries. You should have a max-width, if you want you can specify a min and a max. Use page-speed insights if its speed you're worrying about. Speed is the biggest thing that matters to a lot of people, with legibility and ease of use

Comment: Btw, if you minimise your css and html and optimise your images (which you should anyway) and avoid flash (of course!), using max width should be the least of your worries

Comment: @RachelGallen, haha you are right about "You should have a max-width, if you want you can specify a min and a max"!.....but in regards to "mobile-first", it kind of is and kind of isn't a more fancy term for responsive design. Usually `max-width` media-queries are used to get responsive design that of which normally goes from desktop to mobile deprecation, but the "mobile-first" type of responsive design  goes from mobile to desktop deprecation. It's a noted thing that "mobile-first" is more difficult to design for, but worth the hassel lol....

Comment: @RachelGallen, I can make great designs, but I want only a motorcycle helmet intentionally lol...I want it to look like this... :) ....it's a one-page web app

Comment: @RachelGallen, sorry and your help is awesome still lol...and yes I will, I am open-minded :) PS. I love motorcycles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you have an error in your media query you need to specify `screen and`. Also, I assume that this is for the smaller screen size since gstuff has a wider initial setting.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .gstuff{ 
  width: 250px;
  height: 341px;
  }
}
```

Next you need `position:relative` in your gstuff class. Finally, I absolutely position the tweet button bottom and in the center with:

```
#push-two{
  background-color: #c6c6c4;
  border-bottom:2px inset #FFF;
  border-right:2px inset #FFF;
  border-radius:7px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: blue;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  right: 50%
}
```

Absolute positioning only works when you use position:relative or absolute on the parent container.

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/jchaplin2/pen/WdXwMX)

Comment: It would be great if you forked my pen with this code you just wrote, so I can see how it works **and quickly give you your upvotes**! But I will tryout your answer and come back here and post my results!

Comment: Sure. I will post shortly.

Comment: By the way, I removed   transform: translateY(530px); on your twitter button. Now the page sizes better responsively.

Comment: Not sure how we mis-communicated. It's in the answer. Here it is once more: https://codepen.io/jchaplin2/pen/WdXwMX

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Comment: Can you add an upvote to this Stack Overflow question/post? :)